# Int doesn't work in struct

Tags: c, struct, int

`int` doesn't seem to work with `struct` and I don't know why. I did the same thing as before and it worked but now it doesn't.

This is the main code.

```
int main()
{
    struct elemente {
    char *prod[20];
    int cod[20];
    int cant[20];
    int pret[20];
    };

    struct elemente a[20];
    int i,n=1,p[20];
    char *val[20];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        puts("Numele produsului");
        scanf("%s",&a[i].prod);
        puts("Codul");
        scanf("%i",&a[i].cod);
        puts("Cantitatea");
        scanf("%i",&a[i].cant);
        puts("Pretul");
        scanf("%i",&a[i].pret);
    }
```

It works and I dont see it having problems.

This is where the problem is.

```
puts("Scrieti numele produsului");scanf("%s", &val);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        if(strcmp(val,a[i].prod)==0){
            printf("Codul produsului: %i\n", a[i].cod);
            printf("Cantitatea: %i\n", a[i].cant);
            printf("Pretul: %i\n", a[i].pret);
            //p[i]=a[i].cant*a[i].pret;
            //printf("Valoarea totala a elementelor %i\n",p[i]);
        }
    }
```

The `strcmp` works fine. But it cannot find the integer numbers I have input with my `scanf`. It shows a strange code like "2303134". What did I do wrong?
Also as you can see I need to multiply 2 functions but CodeBlocks has problems with the `*` symbol. How can I fix this?

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` is probably fishy...............

Comment: Defining types in `main`? hm..

Comment: I did the same statement in my previous program. I did not have this kind of problem.

Comment: also, type of `val` will cause pain later...oops, see the `strcmp()`.

Comment: `printf("Codul produsului: %i\n", a[i].cod);` - cod is an array. I don't think you want the `ints` in `elemente` to be arrays.

Comment: Not testing the return value from `scanf` is a sure recipe for surprises.

Comment: Your struct declares *arrays* of `int`s and an *array* of `char *`.  Do you mean it to have a single one of each, and then declare an array of such structs?

Comment: to the name of the product use char prod[20]; no need for * here, since you probably don't want an array of pointers.

Comment: the `int` variables doesn't need to be declared as arrays since you will use an array of structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `struct` contains arrays of each element instead of a single one.  This is also why the multiplication `a[i].cant*a[i].pret` won't compile, because you're attempting to multiply two `int [20]` instead of 2 `int`.

Since you create an array of `struct elemente`, you only need to input one element in each one:

```
struct elemente {
    char prod[50];
    int cod;
    int cant;
    int pret;
};
```

You would then change the `scanf` call to read in `prod` as follows to make sure you don't read more characters than the value can handle:

```
scanf("%49s",a[i].prod);
```

Also, be sure to check the return value of `scanf` to see whether a value was actually read in.

Answer (score 0):

The strange code, in
`printf("Codul produsului: %i\n", a[i].cod)` case, is because you try to print the address of `a[i].cod` instead of the value of integer.

The easiest way to fix this is modify your struct to:

```
struct elemente {
   char *prod[20];
   int cod;
   int cant;
   int pret;
};
```

It seems there's no requirement to assign int arrays in your struct, int variables are sufficient.
After this modification,

```
p[i]=a[i].cant*a[i].pret;
printf("Valoarea totala a elementelor %i\n",p[i]);
```

should be ok to work.